# Find index matrix Matlab

Tags: matlab, indexing, find

I have a problem with matrix dimension and the `find` function.

For each row, I'm trying to find the index related to the value greater than 20 and store the result in another matrix.

For example:

```
A = [
    10  21  30
     1  40  50
     1   0   0 
    50  10   3];


index = 
    2 3 
    2 3
    0
    1
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `find` and `accumarray`

```
>> [r c] = find( A > 20 );
>> index = accumarray( r, c, [], @(x) {x} )

index = 
 [ 2, 3 ]
 [ 2, 3 ]
       []
 [    1 ]
```

Note that `index` is a cellarray.

Comment: Ok, but how can I translate this process if I've a Matrix A (319 rows*26 cols) and 20 is replaced by two vectors upper_bound (319,1) , lower_bound (319,1)
? 
My goal is to check if among a set of 26 curves (319 point for each curve) there are some point greater or lower than upper_bound / lower bound curve in order to exclude a particular set of data if there is at least one point that pass these limits. 

for example:
A = [
18  21  30
1  40  50
..
1   0   0 
50  50   53];
with
upper_bound= [20
45
..
15
55] 
lower_bound=[ 
15
35
.
10
45];
to get:
index_new =
[ 2, 3 ]
[ 1, 3 ]
..
[1,2,3]
[]

Comment: @user2761744 you need to ask a new question on how to replace the simple `find` with a more complicated logical operation.

Answer (score 2):

Does your output have to be in that format? This is very simple:

```
[row,col] = find(A > 20);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you actually need the indices? If not:

```
>> A = [
    10  21  30
     1  40  50
     1   0   0 
    50  10   3];

>> A>20
ans =
     0     1     1
     0     1     1
     0     0     0
     1     0     0
```